# How to add a dialog box to show that an item is not found when it is the case

Tags: javafx, lambda, dialog

a function to search a javafx tableview by entering an ID in a textbox:

```
searchParts.setOnAction(e -> { 
            Integer searchId = Integer.parseInt(txtsearchParts.getText());
            partsTable.getItems().stream().filter(part -> part.getPartID()==searchId).findAny();
            partsTable.getItems().stream()
            .filter(part -> part.getPartID() == searchId)
            .findAny()
            .ifPresent(part -> {
                partsTable.getSelectionModel().select(part);
                partsTable.scrollTo(part);    
            });
        });
```

Comment: Please, reformulate the question, current and desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
searchParts.setOnAction(e -> {
    Integer searchId = Integer.parseInt(txtsearchParts.getText());

    // copy / paste error ?
    //partsTable.getItems().stream()
    //        .filter(part -> part.getPartID() == searchId)
    //        .findAny();

    Optional optional = partsTable.getItems().stream()
            .filter(part -> part.getPartID() == searchId)
            .findAny();

    if(optional.isPresent()) {
        partsTable.getSelectionModel().select(optional.get());
        partsTable.scrollTo(optional.get()); 
    }
    else {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.initOwner(partsTable.getScene().getWindow());
        alert.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        alert.setHeaderText("Item not found!!!");
        alert.setContentText(null);

        alert.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had to add a generic type as follows to make it work: Optional<Part> optional